# Is it possible to sort point particles from a vertex shader?

Tags: webgl, three.js

This is kind of ugly.

[image: sadface.png]

Basically, I have some complex math to position a bunch of point particles. Given there are a lot of particles, it seemed fastest to position all the vertices in the vertex shader. So the real "position" vector of a vertex, as recorded in the geometry in memory, is no where near where the vertex shader ends up putting it.

The problem with this, of course, is depth sorting. A THREE.js `ParticleSystem` can do depth sorting, but it can't sort based on the output of the depth vertex *after* it goes through the vertex shader, as far as I can tell.

is there some kind of workaround with a vertex shader? Or do I need to move all my positioning into JavaScript, where calculation will be much slower? Does render order need to be determined pre-shader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pixels are drawn additively, sorting is not an issue :)

Otherwise: no, except in special cases. Are the particles fully random? Do they need to be? If you sorted in JS, could you sort only occasionally, or keep them pre-sorted in a heap?

Comment: Occlusion helps the perception of depth of each particle, so trying to avoid additive blending. And the points, at least in my current implementation, are on the surface of a rapidly rotating torus. That's got to be the worst case scenario for depth sorting :(

Comment: well then: no, unless you can figure out a deterministic ordinal functions, such that you could always input teh "n" of "nth particle in the sort" and generate the appropriate XYZ from that ordinal value (some patterns do allow this).

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate your particle positions in the vertex shader, and also you can calculate your parameters in terms of distance, you should be able to write a vertex shader that does the sorting. That being said it can be a challenge or impossible to get the parameters in terms of distance.